# How do I implement a database/table as a stack

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I have a state-machine which needs to push/pop some file-names for different users. I would traditionally use stacks as the choice of data structure, but this needs to be done using a database since I don't have a way to retain the data structure between incoming web-requests.

I was wondering what would be a good way to implement the stack functionality using databases ?

I need to support:

- push(fileName, user) : push a fileName for the user
- pop(user) : Pop the top-most fileName for the user

**EDIT**:

I am prototyping an idea, and so I am using sqlite3 with python.

Thanks!

Comment: do you expect the same user to have multiple concurrent connections? what volumes? what Db engine too please?

Comment: @gbn Eventually the same user might have concurrent connections. But for now, I am prototyping an idea and I assume single connection per user

Comment: @brainydexter I would very much like to know what you are trying to do. I get the feeling that you may be creating the wrong solution to your problem. You might want to consider telling us your problem, and asking the best avenue to solve it. Implementing a stack as a database table sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @xenoterracide: The overall intent of what I am trying to do at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145051/how-to-insert-content-in-live-streaming-on-server-side

Stack didn't work completely, so am still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: @brainydexter not really surprised, SQL is a horrible language to implement a stack, because by relational definition a set is unordered, so your stack, will have no order, and you would have to sort it. Perhaps part of your problem is you're telling people what you want the answer to be, and you're asking how. Instead of telling them what the problem is, and asking what. Even your SO question leads the answer to something specific. Try asking for the solution you won't think of.

Comment: I'd like to know where the m3u8 comes in.

Comment: @xenoterracide: I understand your reasoning towards unordered set. I use a timestamp to pop the latest entry. Im sure there are better ways to do this, but sadly my SO post has had no comments/answers. As for m3u8, there is an initial `index.m3u8` which references subplaylists `01.m3u8`. There is a software that generates these for the server and constantly updates these sub-playlists.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Also, I'd recommend posting these things there, since it would help anyone who might read that question. Thanks

Comment: @brainy yeah maybe later, though a database might be the right tech to do it in, but a stack is probably the wrong... ...structure/design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking about which database to use, it really depends on personal preference and what you want out of it. As I'm only familiar with MySQL, I'll answer the other part of the question assuming MySQL:

you will want to use `INNODB` because your table is going to be write-intensive and for large tables, the row-locking of INNODB will be a life-saver over `MyISAM`.

As far as table design, it seems you only really need one table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wordpress`.`<table_name>` (
`id` smallint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNSIGNED,
`user` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`date_insert` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE `userFile`(user, filename)
) ENGINE=`InnoDB`;
```

I went with an arbitrary 'id' column set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` because the primary key is replicated in every entry of every index. So, doing a primary key of (user, filename) could cause performance issues if your filenames are extremely long.

The size of your 'id' column depends on how big your table is going to grow. Unsigned Smallint will give you 65k rows.

User and filenames are varchar, because they'll vary on length drastically I assume.

The `date_insert` is just a way to order your results based on when it was inserted (helpful for your POP)

Comment: I was thinking of making (id, user) combination as the primary key, since I'd like to push or pop based on the user. What do you think ? Also, for the POP operation, wouldn't it be better to find the record for the user with maximum id ?

Comment: @brainydexter http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html has some restrictions on autoincrement (it will re-use 'lower' autoincrement values in certain rare cases). because it's a possibility i went with a date_insert field. As for using (id,user) as Primary key, there's no point except taking up more storage. ID uniquely identifies the row. just 'user' by itself doesn't identify the row, so you could just have a non-unique index on 'userID' instead of a unique (user, filename) if you want.

Answer (score 6):

If you considering an Oracle database you should consider using [Advanced Queuing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_intro.htm#i1005550) with a [LIFO (last in first out) dequeue pattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/oracle-advanced-queuing-lifo).

> At the most basic level of queuing,
>   one producer enqueues one or more
>   messages into one queue. Each message
>   is dequeued and processed once by one
>   of the consumers. A message stays in
>   the queue until a consumer dequeues it
>   or the message expires. A producer may
>   stipulate a delay before the message
>   is available to be consumed, and a
>   time after which the message expires.
>   Likewise, a consumer may wait when
>   trying to dequeue a message if no
>   message is available. An agent program
>   or application may act as both a
>   producer and a consumer.

Comment: classic producer/consumer setup. Thanks for the info, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Hopefully MySQL will get some Adance Queue functionality now that Oracle "owns" mysql...

Comment: @DTest : of course, there's also the distinct possibility that mySQL's now less likely to get advanced features, so Oracle can differentiate between free software and one you have to pay for.

Comment: @Joe thanks for ruining my weekend with that thought!