# Oracle Advanced Queuing LIFO

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

With Oracle's [Advanced Queuing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_intro.htm#i1005550) is there a way to dequeue messages in a LIFO (last in first out) order?  There is [an indication through a lack of information](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/jm_create.htm#ADQUE2916) that this is not an option, but perhaps there is a way to do this such as queuing in a different order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using PL/SQL to dequeue the message (there may be additional JMS limitations-- I don't know enough about the interplay between JMS and AQ), you should be able to use a priority queue to implement LIFO (though it would be a bit hokey).  When you [enqueue a message](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_opers.htm#i1005596), you can specify a priority

> The priority attribute specifies the
>   priority of the message. It can be any
>   number, including negative numbers. A
>   smaller number indicates higher
>   priority.

If you create a sequence that counts back from some really large number, you could assign an ever increasing priority.  Then your prioritized dequeue would get messages in a LIFO order.

Comment: I added the plsql tag.

Comment: Interesting solution.  That definitely sounds like it would work even if it is a bit hokey.

Answer (score 2):

To get LIFO behavior in Oracle, you could implement a stack using [a PL/SQL object](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/10_objs.htm#4139):

> A stack holds an ordered collection of data items. Stacks have a top
>   and a bottom. Items can be added or removed only at the top. So, the
>   last item added to a stack is the first item removed. (Think of the
>   stack of clean serving trays in a cafeteria.) The operations push and
>   pop update the stack while preserving last in, first out (LIFO)
>   behavior.
>
> Stacks have many applications. For example, they are used in systems
>   programming to prioritize interrupts and to manage recursion. The
>   simplest implementation of a stack uses an integer array, with one end
>   of the array representing the top of the stack.

Then you would need to wrap your enqueue/dequeue functions so instead of passing through to AQ, they would instead go to your stack rather than the AQ tables.

Answer (score 0):

The whitepaper for Oracle 12c explicitly calls out using a LIFO queue as an option, but I can't find a good reference in actual the doco as to how you'd do that:

*"Alternately, messages can also be sorted according to enqueue time,
commit time, or priority to get a FIFO or even LIFO order for consuming the messages"*
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/oracleadvancedqueuingwp-2524215.pdf

(one option I can think of is to have a priority-sorted queue with the priority being monotonically increasing at the producer: if an int64 priority is allowed that would give quite a bit of headroom...)